# How to convert this date format in a Time object? "20111210000000 +0100" -> 2011-12-12 00:00

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, datetime

I have datetime in a string and i need to convert it in a Time object.

My datetime string: "20111210000000 +0100"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$ irb
> require 'time'
> s = "20111210000000 +0100"
> Time.parse(s)
```

Just do `Time.parse(yourString)`. Make sure to `require 'time'.`